# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable for a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 3

def f(x):
    x = (x**3-4*x)/(3(x**2)-4)
    return x

while True:
    print(a)
    a = f(a)
```

I'm getting a type error here, and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to run this recursive function, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but: there is no recursion in your code.  Recursion would be if `f` called itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `*` operator after your parentheses. Multiplication is only implied in mathematical notation in this context, in Python it looks like you're trying to call a function.

```
3(x**2)
```

So it would be

```
3*(x**2)
```

For example

```
>>> 3(5*2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    3(5*2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> 3*(5*2)
30
```